# What is the best way to handle a large table of data?

Tags: c#, import-from-csv

I've been playing with Visual C# lately and have formulated a project idea now. I'd like to be able to read in a .csv file and display easy-to-read reports based on the data contained within.

As I'm new to C#, and to real programming at all, I was wondering what is the BEST or recommended way to deal with large amounts of data (with easy, flexible manipulation for data report generation)?

Comment: How large is "large"? Columns? Rows? MB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridViews and Data Sets are something to look into. I bet there's other ones but this is pretty straightforward and works for my needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28VS.71%29.aspx) DataSets work really well for this purpose. If you think you might need to use this data model in several applications, you may also check out [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Storing the Data in a Relational DB like SQL Server is probably the way to go as far as storage goes. To get you started you can use the Free [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)s version.

You can then retrieve the data into [ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28VS.71%29.aspx) Datasets to manipulate the data in C#.